# Insert column value depending on an autoincrement column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table in my SQL Server database with following columns

```
ID |           NAME    |              DOB      |          APPLICATION NO |
1  |          JOHN     |           31/05/1986  |            KPL\2014\1   |
2  |          MARY     |           26/04/1965  |            KPL\2014\2   |
3  |         VARUN     |           15/03/1972  |            KPL\2014\3   |
```

Here column `ID` is an auto increment column and column `APPLICATION NO` is dependent on `ID`.

That means `APPLICATION NO` is the concatenation of `KPL\`, `YEAR` and column value of `ID`.

Then how can I make an insert query?

Comment: You will have to insert a row in table first , get that identity value from table and after that update that row on basis of the identity column value.

Comment: Why don't you just have an "app_name" column (if it's not always KPL), and a Year column ? You could then either build the application_no every time you need it (or make concatenation in a view or a computed column).

Comment: Application number contains many parameters. ID is only one among this. Here i just give a sample table

Comment: are those parameters fixed apart from ID ?

Comment: @SabithPaul and where do all these parameters come from ? Other column of the same row ? Or is it more complicated ?

Comment: from other columns; Like applicant's gender, age limit like that

Comment: @SabithPaul: Is my answer not work for you?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty if it is a concurrent system with hundreds of parallel online registrations how you feel?

Comment: I agree with Raphael: you should simply not store duplicated information.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a computed column ?

I would change the table's definition.

add a "year" column

add an "application_name" column (if it's not always "KPL").

then create your computed column, with the needed fields

```
alter table <yourTable> add computed_application_name as (application_name + '/' + CAST(<yearColumn> as VARCHAR(4) + '/' + <otherColumn> + CAST(id as VARCHAR(MAX))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a computed column:

```
alter table t
    add application_no as ('KPL' + cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(255)) + cast(id as varchar(255));
```

It occurs to me that you really want the year when the row was inserted.  For that purpose, I would recommend adding a `createdat` column and then  using that instead of `getdate()`:

```
alter table t add CreatedAt datetime default getdate();
```

If you have data in the table, then set the value (this is not needed if the table is empty):

```
update table t set CreatedAt = getdate();
```

Then define `application_no`:

```
alter table t
    add application_no as ('KPL' + cast(year(CreatedAt) as varchar(255)) + cast(id as varchar(255));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) get the inserted record Id

```
Declare @Id INT    
Insert Into TABLENAME(NAME ,DOB )
Values('Name','1/1/1990')

Set @Id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

IF(@Id>0)
begin
    declare @col varchar(100)=''
    set @col= 'KPL\' + CONVERT(varchar(4),YEAR(GETDATE()))+'\'  + CONVERT(varchar(4),@Id)

    Update TABLENAME
    SET APPLICATIONNO= @col
    Where ID = @id
end
```

Comment: Don't use `@@identity`, use `scope_identity()` instead, it's much safer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a computed column for 'APPLICATION_NO':

```
create table tbl (
    ID int, 
    NAME varchar(10),              
    DOB  date,          
    APPLICATION_NO as ('KPL\'+cast(year(dob) as char(4))+'\'+cast(id as varchar)) 
)
```

You can further persist and index it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger to run after insert. In your insert, ignore application_no. And your trigger update this column based on ID.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TRIGGER_TABLE1] ON  TABLE1
    AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    UPDATE TABLE1
    SET APPLICATION_NO = 'KPL\' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(GETDATE())) + '\' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ID)
    WHERE APPLICATION_NO IS NULL

END
```

**EDIT:** This way, you should be able to use other columns values as well. APPLICATION_NO just need to accept NULL values. So you control like this what will be updated or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it by yourself with an insert statement:

- assuming that you want to insert data from another table
- and `TABLE1` is the table you described in your question and `TABLE2` would be the table you want to import data from:

  ```
  DECLARE @MAXID INT
  SELECT @MAXID = MAX(ID) FROM TABLE1

  INSERT INTO TABLE1
  (NAME,DOB,APPLICATION_NO)
  SELECT
  NAME,
  DOB,
  'KPL\' 
  + CONVERT(CHAR(4),YEAR(GETDATE()) +'\'
  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @MAXID + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NAME)) AS APPLICATION_NO
  FROM TABLE2
  ```